# How to clear a JTextArea by pressing enter and remain on the same line

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to clear a JTextArea of 2 rows after pressing enter.
I set a KeyListener that triggers when the pressed key is enter; I use `setText("")` and it clears it but my problem is that it goes to the next line and the text into the area remain made by 2 lines but I want only one line. I also tried to set the caret but it doesn't work, it places the caret at the beginning of the second line.
Here's the listener code, I think it's enough because this does all the work, in case you need more code let me know.

```
private class AscoltatoreKey implements KeyListener{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){  //viene azionato quando viene premuto invio
            String espressione = input.getText().trim();  //prendo il testo dall'area di input
            valutatore.addEspressione(espressione); //aggiungo l'espressione al valutatore
            numeroEspressioni++;
            areaEquazioni.append(numeroEspressioni + ") " + espressione +"\n");  //scrivo l'espressione nella lista delle espressioni
            try{
                areaSoluzioni.append(numeroEspressioni + ") " + valutatore.risolvi() + "\n"); //scrivo l'espressione nella lista delle soluzioni
            }catch (Exception exc){
                areaSoluzioni.append(numeroEspressioni + ") " + "Espressione malformata!" + "\n");
            }
            input.setText(""); //svuoto l'area di input per prepararmi a ricevere la nuova espressione
            input.setCaretPosition(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Never add a KeyListener to a Swing text component. Use Key Bindings instead.

Comment: Please see edits to answer. If anything confuses you about the answer, please comment back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never add a KeyListener to a JTextComponent such as a JTextArea as this can ruin the underlying function of the text component. Instead use what the Swing library uses when it wants to trap key strokes on a component: use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

For example if you bound the enter key stroke to an Action that cleared the JTextArea, your code would work. In the code below we get the InputMap for the JTextArea for when it has focus:

```
int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
InputMap inputMap = textArea.getInputMap(condition);
```

and also get the JTextArea's ActionMap

```
ActionMap actionMap = textArea.getActionMap();
```

then we tie the two maps together, we bind them using the same String constant, here I use the `.toString()` for my KeyStroke, but any unique (one not also used in the current InputMap) String will do. The action simply clears the JTextArea that caused the action to occur (the source of the Action):

```
KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);   
inputMap.put(enterKey, enterKey.toString());
actionMap.put(enterKey.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JTextArea txtArea = (JTextArea) e.getSource();
        txtArea.setText("");
    }
});
```

My full MCVE example of the above in action:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClearTextAreaEg extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);

    public ClearTextAreaEg() {
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
        InputMap inputMap = textArea.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = textArea.getActionMap();

        KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);

        inputMap.put(enterKey, enterKey.toString());
        actionMap.put(enterKey.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextArea txtArea = (JTextArea) e.getSource();
                txtArea.setText("");
            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ClearTextAreaEg mainPanel = new ClearTextAreaEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClearTextAreaEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's one of the first time that I use swing so I actually don't know what "focus" and those 2 maps are, could you go a little more in details?

Comment: @Andreascopp: please check out the relevant [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will explain most of your confusion.

Comment: Ok I think that now I understood most of what you wrote, but why do you use ´KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);´  and ´new AbstractAction()´ ? On the documentation you sent it uses a string to specify the key stroke and it didn't create any object as the value but uses javax.swing.Action objects

Comment: The KeyStroke needs to go into the InputMap as the first parameter of the `put(...)` method, and it must be a KeyStroke object, not a String. The *second* parameter of this method must be a String, and it must be the *same* String used to bind to the ActionMap. Look up the API for InputMap and ActionMap and study both of their respective `put(...)` methods.

Comment: Another question, is this ´JTextArea txtArea = (JTextArea) e.getSource()´ necessary? Can't you just write ´textArea.setText("")´ since that you know what to clear?

Comment: You *can* skip that if you desire, but if you want to put the binding code in its own class, or use the binding for more than one JTextArea, I used the current code for safety reasons.

Comment: I understood that the first parameter must be a KeyStroke object but in the documentation you sent, the KeyStroke is created by `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER")` for example, what is the difference with you way to create it? 
Why you used `new AbstractAction()` as the second parameter in the actionMap put?

edit: ok thanks for the last answer!

Comment: @Andreascopp: There are more than one way to get a KeyStroke object, and the [KeyStroke API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html) will tell you what methods are available for creation. Please check it out. As for the AbstractAction, an `Action` object is required for the 2nd parameter of the ActionMap's `put(...)` method. Think of an AbstractAction like an "ActionListener on steroids". There's a tutorial on how to use Actions, whose link I don't have but you can and should Google it.

Comment: Ok, I think I got everything now, I'm going to check out what you said. Really thanks for everything! You've really helped me out and you've been very kind :D sorry if I bothered you!